# CSS - Bg color for text

Tags: html, css

Please got through this code and see the output. What my requirement is I need to give line-height to the text. But it is effecting the text background color. I don't want to put all the sentences in separate divs or p. And I can't use height property for text bg color. Do you have any idea? If that so please share. Thanks

```css
.nb-semnox-impact-grid {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: normal;
}
.nb-semnox-impact-grid span {
  font-family: 'GilroyBold';
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.nb-semnox-impact-grid span.nb-bold-font {
  font-size: 135px;
}
.nb-semnox-impact-grid span.nb-bg-yellow::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff200;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
.nb-semnox-impact-grid span.nb-bg-blue::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #78d0f0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="nb-semnox-impact-grid">
  <span class="nb-bold-font"> 47% </span> of <br> the feature <span class="nb-bg-yellow"> #landingpage </span> <br> was <span class="nb-bg-blue"> #meeting time </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update the snippet I made for you with anything missing - for example nothing is yellow here

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here, or what you're trying to accomplish. Just a guess: rather than changing the ``line-height`` property, maybe you need to change the ``margin`` or ``padding``?

Comment: font-size : 2em; ?

Comment: Change line height of what? The parent or individual highlighted items?

Comment: Why use a pseudo-element that covers the span - why not just apply the background directly to the span?

Answer (score -1):

just add the `line-height` with the size you want inside the `span.nb-bg-yellow` or `span.nb-bg-blue`.